# New SSL certificate verification errors - what's the root cause?

Tags: ssl, openssl

My application uses the Close API (https://developer.close.com/) to store user data. Our testing environment is now getting SSL errors when trying to write to it:

```rb
Faraday::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (certificate has expired))
```

What could the cause be? My first assumption reading the error message is that the Close certificates might have expired. But that seems unlikely - the service is generally well-maintained, and we are not having any issues in production.

The next thing I considered was that perhaps the certificate store on our server is out of date. That would not surprise me much, because the server is running Ubuntu 14, and [other people are experiencing problems there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366704/how-to-install-latest-ca-certificates-on-ubuntu-14). But we have multiple machines with the same configuration, and only one of them is giving us trouble. Is it possible this is the root cause?

Comment: The LetsEncrypt compatibilty chain (which that server uses, like many) causes 'expired' depending on the version of OpenSSL used (Trusty supplies 1.0.1f but an API may be different) and the contents of the cert store, which _if_ defaulted depends _partly_ on the ca-certificates package (last version in standard repo appears to be 20170717~14.04.2) but also on whether running `update-ca-certificates` deleted the _expired_ DST root (I've seen reports it does). Either or both of these two different factors could be called 'out of date'; which exactly applies to yours?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 On the broken machine, we had openssl 1.0.1f & the DST root was *not* deleted. Running update-ca-certificates also didn't remove it. Removing it manually was what fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce:

```sh
$ openssl s_client -CApath /dev/null -showcerts -connect api.close.com:443 -servername api.close.com
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=Sep 30 14:01:15 2021 GMT
verify return:0
```

The problem turned out to be [the recent deprecation of the DST root certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/). An old root certificate (DST) was deprecated on Sep 30, and the modern version (ISRG) is now expected.

The testing server still had the DST and ISRG certificates installed, whereas all the other machines only had ISRG. I assume that something about this particular API was looking preferentially for the DST certificate and ignoring ISRG unless it was the only one.

To solve: Remove DST cert from `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla` and leave ISRG one there - try the openssl command above, now it works.